# How to get negative values plotted in reactable bar chart?

Tags: r, reactable

I'm having some difficulty getting my negative bar chart to appear in my `reactable` table. I have example code below and as you'll see, my positive values are plotted, but not my negative ones. I'm stuck on what I'm missing, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(htmltools)
library(reactable)

bar_chart_pos_neg <- function(label, value, height = "16px",
                              pos_fill = "green", neg_fill = "red") {
  pos_chart <- div(style = list(flex = "1 1 0"))
  neg_chart <- div(style = list(flex = "1 1 0"))
  width <- value
  
  if (value < 0) {
    bar <- div(style = list(marginLeft = "8px", background = neg_fill, width = width, height = height))
    chart <- div(style = list(display = "flex", alignItems = "center", justifyContent = "flex-end"), label, bar)
    neg_chart <- tagAppendChild(neg_chart, chart)
  } else {
    bar <- div(style = list(marginRight = "8px", background = pos_fill, width = width, height = height))
    chart <- div(style = list(display = "flex", alignItems = "center"), bar, label)
    pos_chart <- tagAppendChild(pos_chart, chart)
  }
  
  div(style = list(display = "flex"), neg_chart, pos_chart)
}

data <- data.frame(
  Spread = c(3.8741435, -10.7573310, 6.8234219, 10.1194614, 3.6772631,
             -4.2870001, 4.9933226, 2.6914581, -7.0133144, 4.9004934,
             -8.6499655, -1.4826557, -0.2060462, 0.3289249, -2.1613399,
             -4.5594886)
)

reactable(data, bordered = TRUE, columns = list(
  Spread = colDef(
    name = "Spread",
    cell = function(value) {
      label <- paste0(round(value), " pts")
      bar_chart_pos_neg(label, value)
    },
    align = "center",
    minWidth = 400
  )
))
```

Comment: I run your code and it returns "(Error in div(style = list(flex = "1 1 0")) : could not find function "div")"

Comment: Sorry, @PeaceWang. I forgot to add the 'htmltools' package to the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for width  should be positive.

```
width <- abs(value)
```